# Concatenating all match values in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to utilize the index and match functions in Excel to return all matching values concatenated together in a single cell? For example - the if I have the following values:

[image: sample data]

I would like to find that specific date and training and use index and matching to return all three of those people, comma separated in the one cell. I've tried to do it myself but I can only get them to return all values in separate cells then running a concatenate on those cells to get what I want which is too many steps for how I'd like to automate it.

I've tried to use the following function:

```
Function Combo(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As 
Integer, Char As String)

Dim I As Long
Dim xRet As String
For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
    If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
        If xRet = "" Then
            xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
        Else
            xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
        End If
    End If
Next
SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far?

Comment: Type `=textjoin()` into a cell. Do you get a `#NAME?` error?

Comment: @Jeeped I do, doesn't appear as a function

Comment: You've stuffed three columns of usable data into a single unusable concatenated string. Now you want to split the individual pieces of data out as criteria to create another concatenated string. Is that an accurate representation of your current dilemma?

Comment: @Jeeped I'll try to explain myself better, I have a list of training records with expiry dates and I've got an identifier for each course (which comprises multiple records) - my aim was to be able to fetch everyone with a training record against that identifier and combine it into a single cell.

Comment: Your sample data is what is confusing the question, it looks like anything that uses the same letters is to be concatenated but what I believe you are saying is if it matches the date and the course ID it should be concatenated regardless of what the names are. Correct?

Comment: Are you saying that *'Robert Green - 06/07/2019 - Training A'* is not in one cell? That it is in three cells side by side?

Comment: Dan, Jeeped - I have fixed the question and added a screencapture. Apologies for not being clear, I felt that this would be relatively simple and when it wasn't I rushed the question.